# Разиница между "ложитесь" и "лягте"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли разница между словами "ложитесь" и "лягте"? Или второе - просторечное? Просто, вспомнилась песенка Высоцкого: "Если вы в своей квартире, / Лягте на пол. Три-четыре..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет,  ляг(те) - это не просторечие. это нормативный вариант. Ложиться - глагол несовершенного вида,лечь  - глагол совершенного вида. ложитесь и лягте  - формы от повелительного наклонения от этих инфинитивов.